# Blazor WASM Azure AD Connect To Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, blazor, azure-ad-msal, blazor-client-side

I have blazor wasm with Azure AD Connect. I am following the docs from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1). I can login and get access token just fine. But the problem is when I am trying to use the access token to call API from https://graph.microsoft.com I can't use it and the error said `Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.`. When I debug from https://jwt.ms the `aud` filled with my Client ID not MS Graph.
I already tried add

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
}
```

in Client Project but still can't use the token for accessing MS Graph. Any more that I need to add?

Comment: What is the `aud` filled in your access token currently?

Comment: ClientId from my Azure App Registration

Comment: Before you set "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" as the scope, what is the previous value?

Comment: The same. The `aud` is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and site data can persist across app updates and interfere with testing and troubleshooting.

You have used the correct value `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` for `DefaultAccessTokenScopes`. But it doesn't seem to be in effect.

Please refer to [Troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#troubleshoot) to avoid the impact of caching.

Comment: I already tried using InPrivate mode in Edge but still the same though.

Comment: @albilaga Please use Fiddler4 to catch a request of getting token to see what the scope is.

Comment: I already check scope on `Network` tab in developer tools and the scope showing `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid profile` but yeah the token still can't access MS graph.